# Dart: how can I convert a Set to a Map entry in the toJson method?

Tags: json, dart, encode

How can I convert a Set to a valid map entry in the toJson() method? My object looks like this:

```
class MyCustom{
  String name = '';
  Set<String> mySet= new Set();

  Map toJson() {
    Map map = new Map();
    map['name'] = this.name;
    map['mySet'] = this.mySet;
    return map
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is convert it to a List. Set, for reasons I do not understand, will not work with the JSON.encode method.

```
List<String> myList = new List();
...
map['myList'] = this.myList;
```

or if you want to keep your collection as a Set.

```
map['mySet'] = this.mySet.toList();
```

Comment: A `Set` has no default JSON conversion in the `JSON.encode` method because JSON doesn't have a representation for it. We could have let any `Iterable` be automatically converted to a `List`, but decided on not being too clever - we only accept types that are converted back to the same type by `JSON.decode` (`List`, `Map<String,?>` and basic types).